# Searching through a huge list of short strings

Tags: string, search, text, indexing

I have a HUGE plaintext file with 1 billion strings, where average string length is around 10-12, with potential duplicates, and each string is on a different line. My task is that, when given a query string, find the line of first match if the string exists in my file, or return "not found."

A natural solution is to run `grep -m1 -n '^querystring$'` every time, which takes around 15-20 seconds, and this does not require extra storage and is not memory-intensive. Is this a good solution, or is there something much better?

(N.B. As a rough guide, my storage requirement: <10GB, and memory requirement: <16GB)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple python code for that:

```
file = 'file.txt'
queryLine = 0
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if <YOUR QUERY> in line: return queryLine 
        else: queryLine += 1
```

this way, you break when finding a match, instead using `grep` and every time go over the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution:

When you `open` a file you get an iterator giving you one line at a time, which is very memory efficient. My suggestion is to enumerate the file and get the first line line meeting your criterion like this:

```
def first_occurrence(filename, query):
    with open(filename) as f:
        filtered = (i for i, line in enumerate(f, 1) if query in line)
        return next(filtered, 'not found')
```

If there's no such line, the default value `'not found'` is returned. `filtered = (...)` builds a generator by employing a generator expression. Generators are iterators, so this part is memory efficient as well.